# Strange html table layout

Tags: html, html-table

I have been working on a project now for a few weeks and I've come up against something strange happening with the bottom of the table,

This is the part where its going strange:
(sorry, it's quite long but its towards the bottom!)

http://pastebin.com/mtTNR4CH

and this is the page that its happening on:

http://www.upsandgeneratorparts.com/auction/daily-deal-3,name,100196,auction_id,auction_details

I don't know where to start, I've tried opening it all in Dreamweaver, but only found a lonely `</td>` that had nothing to do with it!

Would be very grateful of any help!

Comment: stop using tables for your layout and you should be just fine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you notice that the last `tr`:

```
<tr>
    <td width="10"><img src="themes/multi_blue/img/c3.gif" width="10" height="10"></td>
    <td width="100%" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #bbbbbb;"><img src="themes/multi_blue/img/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1"></td>
    <td width="10"><img src="themes/multi_blue/img/c4.gif" width="10" height="10"></td>
</tr>
```

Contains three cells while the main tr contains only 2? use `colspan` or add a `td` to the footer `tr` and tell me how it looks.

**EDIT:**
I took another look. Add the below code to the upper `tr` before the first `td` you have now. You're missing your left ruler in the main row, you have only one for the right side.

```
<td width="10"><img src="themes/multi_blue/img/c3.gif" width="10" height="10"></td>
```

Comment: where did you want the `colspan` going?

Comment: @OliverWhysall Here's a short tutorial (top on google) for colspan: http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/tables/index_famsupp_30.html. Basically, you need to add it on one of the td the upper tr to instruct that td takes the space of 2 cells.

Comment: edited the answer, you should be able to copy-paste the solution. but, I'm not sure I'm doing you a favor here :)

Comment: I had tried that by adding:
`<td colspan="2" width="10" style="border-right: 1px solid #bbbbbb;"><img src="themes/<?=$setts['default_theme'];?>/img/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1"></td>` adding the colspan="2" in there, but nothing seemed to have changed

Comment: @OliverWhysall check out my answer EDIT, it should work for you now.

Comment: sorry mr. kav, I'm completely lost here - by upper tr do you mean the `tr` ending on line 1313?

Comment: I've done that - its made it better, but it's still not quite there :s revised pastebin: http://pastebin.com/pDCEiGJq

Comment: apologies :) this is where I need to stop, debugging HTMLs is fun! but very time consuming. I have no other suggestion, but to slowly and painfully debug the HTML elements until it looks right. I'm not sure if you're using tools for this purpose, but I highly recommend Google Chrome Developer Tools (can be accessed by Ctrl+Shift+I on pc) for going over the HTML and looking for cavities/code discrepancies.

Comment: thanks for your help mr kav! i've got this page all broken up into header.tpl.php, details.tpl.php and footer.tpl.php so its a nightmare finding anything! i'll open it in dreamweaver again and see what i can find

Comment: @OliverWhysall good luck Oliver, but may I also suggest working backwards? Try looking at the final product using Chrome Developer Tools, try isolating the td/div/etc... and see if you can indicate a segment that doesn't look right. Then you can back to the php files. Another approach would be taking the HTML and pasting it into a plain html file, now start cutting away chunks of code until you see the problem resolved. That's the point/chunk that you need to rewrite.

Answer (score 1):

Start by using a [Doctype that triggers standards / strict mode](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/quirksmode.html) (since quirks mode is too inconsistent to develop new stuff in), writing [valid HTML](http://validator.w3.org/) (browser bugs are bad enough with good markup) and not using [tables for layout](http://www.hotdesign.com/seybold/) (this isn't the '90s).